# Dynamic MC's path with localToGlobal Problems

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, dynamic, path

I'm adding several instances of an MC (bread_mc) into a container MC (wall_mc). wall_mc has been added to a shop class and that is where i'm called the rest of my functions from. Also the wall_mc is scrolled left and right with mouseX & mouseY values. I've set up a function to add the bread_mc to the wall at different x/y positions.

Function call:

```
fillShelves(bread_mc,Bread,600,200);
```

Function:

```
 function fillShelves(productMc:MovieClip,className:Class,productX:Number, productY:Number) {

        newProduct = new className();
        newProduct.x=productX;
        newProduct.y=productY;
        shelf_mc.addChildAt(newProduct,1);

        newProduct.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragProduct, false, 0, true);

    }
```

I've added a drag/drop where the bread_mc will snap back to it's shelf x/y position. However i'd like that when user MOUSE_DOWN on bread_mc it is added to the highest depth so, while dragged, it stays infront of other mc's (a person with a shopping cart for example).

My problem is, whenever I call the function dragProduct();

```
function dragProduct(e:MouseEvent):void {

    currMC = (e.target as MovieClip);
    this.addChild(currMC); 
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropProduct);

    }
```

The damn bread_mc I click on moves to the right by the same amount that I've scrolled the wall_mc. I have tried forcing the currMC to stick with the mouseX/Y but that would need an ENTER_FRAME function and that seems so convoluted.

I researched and found localToGlobal. Methods simliar to this:

```
point = new Point(currMC.x, currMC.y);
    currMC.localToGlobal(point);
    trace(point.x);
```

I really don't even know if i'm using it right, But I think my problem lies in the fact that I need the currMC path to travel up the display list tree and get the global stage X/Y position. I'm not too sure how to implement a dynamic path with the localToGlobal method.

Any help would be appreciated. Even if it's go here>read this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your dragged `bread_mc` moveclip moves because it is being move to a different container that has a different origin. In your `fillShelves` function you are adding `bread_mc` as a child of `shelf_mc`. But in the `dragProduct` function you are adding it to `this`. Just try adding `bread_mc` to `shelf_mc` rather than `this`. And forget about all the localToGlobal stuff.

When you call `addChild`, it will bring the target to the front of all its siblings.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. The reason I want to do this is because I have a shopper_mc added to the stage (on top of the shelf_mc, not in) And they walk beside the shelf as the shelf scrolls. So, as you can imagine, the dragged product (bread_mc) will never sit above the shopper_mc and I was just hoping to correct this by adding the bread_mc to the stage while it is dragged and then returning it back to it's nested position in the shelf_mc if it is stopDrag()ed. That is why I was hoping to use localToGlobal.